# Select2 does not stylize during initialization using YADCF

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-select2, yadcf

I do not know why yacdf does not want to style select2. When I run select2 outside the initialization yacdf to select, it is stylized correctly but this is a non-sense solution, I would like the select to be stylized using YADCF:

I`m using:

yadcf v0.9.2, select2 v4.0.3

yadcf has been added as the last item in the css and javascript lists.

I use it this way:

```
return this.container
            .find('#' + matcher.ticketsDatatableName)
            .DataTable({
                order: [[1, 'desc']],
                stateSave: true,
                dom: 'lB<"#issue-type-name-container">frtip',
                scrollY: '500px',
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                colReorder: true,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'colvis',
                        columns: matcher.getHideableColumns(columns)
                    }
                ],
                columns: columns,
                initComplete: function () {
                    yadcf.init(App.matcher.bindTicketsListDatatable(), [
                        {
                            column_number: App.matcher.bindTicketsListDatatable().column('issue_type_name:name').index(),
                            filter_type: 'multi_select',
                            select_type: 'select2',
                            filter_container_id: 'issue-type-name-container',
                            filter_reset_button_text: false
                        }
                    ]);

                    // $('#issue-type-name-container select').select2();
                }
            });
```

And result its:

[image]

I think problem is in 731 line in yadcf js file:

`console.log(selectObject);`
`$selectObject.select2(select_type_options);`

But this element exists in dom:

[image]

[image]

I do not understand what I am doing wrong or is there anyone able to help me?

Comment: try loading select2 before yadcf

Comment: You mean files or what ? if files, then yadcf is loaded at the end

Comment: the 731 is not related to the issue, please provide a simplified jsfiddle test page